# Chess players in tv commercials?

Tags: history, famous-players, film, fiction

There are a lot of tv commercials featuring football players, cricket players, etc. How about chess players? Two commercials come to mind.

1. [Kasparov vs Machine Pepsi Commercial](https://youtu.be/cUqXr9Jlhwc)
2. [Korchnoi Milk commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUZSCb4EVrM)

Are there more like this? Recent chessable and chess.com commercials don't count, since I doubt they appeared on tv.

Comment: I really don't get why you got a down-vote for that question. I find that very interesting and the two examples are pretty funny.

Comment: @Christian idk if this is off topic

Comment: Then there shouldn't be that 'famous-players'  tag you used if you are only only ever allowed to ask strictly game related questions.

Comment: @Christian just found out there is a fiction tag as well

Comment: Well, "big-list" obviously. Even if it is small, it's a big list ;-) Anyway: Carlsen, also obviously. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h4HuUEGB-g Also, google "chess commercials compilation" on Youtube.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann thank you!

Comment: Carlsen, Clothing industry. Kasparov, Schweppes. Certainly Agdestein, but not as a chess player. Probably Anand, Kasimdjanov, Karpov ?

Comment: Alireza Firouzja, obviously fashion

Comment: @NicolasFormichella there is a commercial?

Comment: He appeared on fashion magazines covers recently, don't know if there is a video commercial but as cover head yes

Comment: @NicolasFormichella interesting

Answer (score 4):

I remember this one by Vishy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVjYzB4NCb8 .

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list I have compiled. Feel free to add more examples.

**Vishy Anand**

- [AMD #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVjYzB4NCb8)
- [AMD #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyqU-pRjF6c)
- [TVH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF5tuJt47b0)
- [Crocin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA4eFN-60l8)
- [Union Bank of India](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eyb3wJ_KEXQ)
- [Complan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66wedH1Qa24)
- [Edify](https://youtu.be/0VGwXv75Yug)
- [Specsmakers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E71j-zMvb2g)
- [Subway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNWsHU25pZE)

**Magnus Carlsen**

- [Altibox](https://youtu.be/SuNCvHlgiAM)
- [G-Star Raw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h4HuUEGB-g)
- [Unibet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iocN274B33s&pp=ygURbWFnbnVzIGNhcmxzZW4gYWQ%3D)
- [Porsche](https://youtu.be/2DJw1--8Tcs)
- [Felleskjøpet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSv6n7jgBYw)

**Garry Kasparov**

- [Pepsi](https://youtu.be/cUqXr9Jlhwc)
- [AltaVista](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RU5OwLS7DRs&pp=ygUSa2FzcGFyb3YgYWx0YXZpc3Rh)

**Victor Korchnoi**

- [Milk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUZSCb4EVrM)